# How to fix broken styles of validation bubble in Chrome for Android?

Tags: android, html, validation, google-chrome

I'm using HTML5 validation to validate a form. The validation process works but the problem is how validation messages appears in Chrome for Android.

[image]

How can I fix this? It happens every time I test.

Comment: You can no longer edit the styles in webkit...

http://superuser.com/questions/712727/chrome-html5-notifications-displaying-white-font-on-white-background

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have two problems:

1. The shadowdom of older webkit versions can be targeted with general selectors. I.e.: `form.my-form div` Try to use classes as last selector part: `.my-form .my-div`. Maybee you should also check wether a `* {box-sizing: content-box;}` needs to be addressed. Alternativley you can fix those styles, by re-adding right styles using the webkit pseudos: http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#Formvalidationmessage and http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#WebKitr82180orlater
2. I'm not sure wether this is happening, here (your picture is not clear). There is an overflow bug in older webkit versions. Do not use overflow: hidden with positioned element as a wrapper for your form fields